# incomplete solution while printing frequencies of every element in an a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays

I have been given a sorted array & I have to print the frequency of every element in Time Complexity of O(n) & Space Complexity O(1)

eg -> arr[] = {1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3}

Output :

1 -> 2

2- > 4

3 -> 3

My code works fine for every element apart from the last element. It does not print the last element's frequency . Can someone suggest me a solution

```
public static void frequency(int[] arr){
        int count=1;
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){

            if(i==arr.length-1){
                if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
                    System.out.print(arr[i-1] + " -> ");
                    System.out.println(count);
                }else{
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " -> ");
                    System.out.println("1");
                }
            }

            if(arr[i]!=arr[i-1]){
                System.out.print(arr[i-1] + " -> ");
                System.out.println(count);
                count=1;
            }else{
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you forgot to increase the count here `if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
                    System.out.print(arr[i-1] + " -> ");
                    System.out.println(count);
                }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void frequency(int[] arr){
        int count=1;
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
//option 1
//            if(i==arr.length-1){
//                if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
//                    count++;  //increase if it is the same
//                    System.out.print(arr[i-1] + " -> ");
//                    System.out.println(count);
//                }else{
//                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " -> ");
//                    System.out.println("1");
//                }
//            }

            if(arr[i]!=arr[i-1]){
                System.out.print(arr[i-1] + " -> ");
                System.out.println(count);
                count=1;
            }else{
                count++;
            }
            //option 2
            if(i==arr.length-1){
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " -> ");
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my solution to your issue. The first option would be to directly just increment it before you print out because the logic is if its the same increment count. However, because the if else statement can be long and redundant, it would make more sense to allow your existing logic which checks if the element is same or different to previous element to take care of it.

Thus option 2. If it is same, the count would be incremented, however not printed, but if it is different, it would print the second last, not printing last. The new if statement i added would print out the final count if last and second last are the same, or the last if the last and second last are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to using a `count` is to store the position, initialized to zero, of the start of each sequence of repeating characters. You then compare each element, starting at one, to the value at this position. If they're different the length of the sequence is given by the difference in these positions.

There's also the trick of iterating to one past the end of the array (`i <= arr.length`) and outputting the length of the final sequence when this condition is met `if (i == arr.length...`. This has the advantage that you don't have to handle it separately after the `for` loop.

```
public static void frequency(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == arr.length || arr[i] != arr[j]) {
            System.out.println(arr[j] + " -> " + (i - j));
            j = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
frequency(new int[] {1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3});
```

Output:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 3
```

Comment: Nice explanation & approach. Thanks!!